# How build production Angular8 App for IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, production

I faced with problem when I try run build app for IE11. When I run serve with **--configuration=es5** - it works. But I build with **--configuration=es5** - I take not prod version.
How I can build prod version for IE11?

My **browserlist** has "**IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.**"

My **tsconfig.json** has **"target": "es5"**.

My **tsconfig-es5.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

My **angular.json**

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ...
          },
          "configurations": {
            "es5": {
              "tsConfig": "tsconfig-es5.app.json"
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [{
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
              }],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [{
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "charity:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "es5": {
              "browserTarget": "charity:build:es5"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "charity:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        ...
    }
```

I trying add **"compilerOptions": { "target": "es5" }** for **tsconfig.app.json**, but I take error message for IE11(Google Chrome works):

> ERROR Sys.ParameterCountException: Sys.ParameterCountException:
>   Parameter count mismatch.

[Angular 8 build does not work with IE though serve works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58397260/angular-8-build-does-not-work-with-ie-though-serve-works-fine)

Answer (score 1):

The issue might due to "build-optimizer" from Angular. I refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966104/build-in-production-mode-results-in-empty-page-while-build-in-dev-mode-works-per) and tried to disable the build optimizer, then it can work well in IE 11 with Angular 8.0.3.

You can run `ng build --prod --build-optimizer=false` or change the value of `buildOptimizer` in **angular.json** to `false`. Then deploy the production bundles in the **dist** folder to the web server.